# Associating an OptionGroup with a MySQL 5.7 database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to enable Audit logs for Aurora MySQL (5.7) RDS instance on AWS and for that I need (based on the official documentation) to create an Option Group and associate it with the database.

I'm able to create the option group, but I see no option to associate the option group in the RDS console (neither on the cluster or instance configuration). I only have options for the parameter group. All the instructions that I see online and on the official documentation point to an option that seems that is not visible for some reason.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the aws cli: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-instance.html

Comment: Hey Ricardo, can you exactly screenshot what you expect to see, and what you're not seeing? Alternatively, as @jordanm has suggested, you can use the CLI/SDK/API etc. to do this programatically. But I am intrigued to see what _exactly_ isn't visible for you.

Comment: I don't what I was supposed to see, usually information found online points to the Modify instance page on the database instance and to add the option group. But I don't have such option under the Database options. I think I'll try the CLI option.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to execute this via CLI as @jordanm proposed didn't work, but the error pointed me to the solution. Apparently Aurora MySQL is a different engine from MySQL, this engine doesn't seem to support option groups, or at least the procedure to enable the logs is different, as documented here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Auditing.html.

I followed this and now the audit logs are working.